# Как проверить отправлен ли POST ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть форма которая отправляется POST ajax. Как проверить отправилась ли форма по jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'handeler.php',
   success: function(){
      //redirect
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    echo 'Это ajax запрос!';

}
```

Comment: А это в обработчик нужно засунуть ?

Comment: POST и ajax запрос отправляется на сервер, на сервере, как я понял, запросы обрабатываются PHP. Вот в скрипте PHP вы можете проверить...

Comment: У меня есть файл отправки, файл обработчик (экшон), и ajax скрипт в другом файле. Мне нужно ари верном заполнении формы сделать редирект

Comment: В обработчик добавьте